# Is this patent abandoned?

Tags: prior, us6029723

In reference to the patent: [US6029723](https://www.google.com/patents/US6029723)

Answer (score 1):

I went to the [US Public Pair](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) to check this patent's status. Checking the Fees tab yields "Patent expired on 02/29/2004 due to non-payment of maintenance fee.". It might be possible to resurrect the patent, but in any case it would expire normally by Oct. 7, 2018.

Answer (score -1):

According to my search, patent is already expired as 20 years have already passed. Below is the link.
http://patft1.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PALL&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsrchnum.htm&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=4261226.PN.&OS=PN/4261226&RS=PN/4261226

Comment: 1981 us patents expired 17 years after grant

Comment: The link is to the wrong patent.

Comment: @EricShain oh ..